# Proxy error while accessing the application

Tags: java, apache, webserver

I have an apache proxy between browser and my custom web server. So after starting the webserver, I can access my web application for like 4-5 hours. After that I get this error

> Proxy Error The proxy server received an invalid response from an
>   upstream server. The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server

To access the web application again, I have to restart the web server. I tried to check the log I got from my web server and only error in that log , I am finding is this

> com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
>   due to underlying exception:
>
> ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION **
>
> java.net.SocketException MESSAGE: Connection timed out
>
> STACKTRACE:
>
> java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:146)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:113)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:160)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:188)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1910)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2304)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2803)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1573)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1665)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3170)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3099)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.Statement.execute(Statement.java:695)
>           at hra.database.Pool.getConnection(Pool.java:62)
>
> ** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
>
> Last packet sent to the server was 925624 ms ago.

And I tried to fix this database error, but I still get the above mentioned proxy error, so definitely the log information is not useful.

This is what I am getting from Apache Proxy log

> (70007)The timeout specified has expired: proxy: error reading status
>   line from remote server

Does anyone know what can be the issue or any helpful pointers to fix this issue?

Comment: "I have to restart the web server" <-- which one? Yours?

Comment: Yes, my custom written webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. apache proxy fails because customwebserver does not answer. your
2. customwebserver logs a crash waiting for mysql to answer. rebooting
3. customwebserver fixes it, so mysql is not the problem. it looks like the problem the way your customwebserver handles its connections to mysql.

   can we see your jdbc config?  do you have autoReconnect=true ?

Comment: I use jdbc connection through a Pool like this new Pool("jdbc:mysql://" + host + "/mydatabase?jdbcCompliantTruncation=false", "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver", windows ? 2 : 20)   No autoReconnect=true. I don't think it is a good idea to use autoreconnect in connections pool.

Answer (score 1):

What is likely happening is that your up-stream server is shutting itself down because of inactivity. Find the setting on the server that controls that and turn it up.

Comment: Whichever one the proxy is complaining about responding poorly.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you see two connection timeout errors

- Apache Proxy Web server timing out while connecting to custom web server
- Custom web server timing out while connecting to database

If the timeout set on proxy server is *less* than timeout set for database connection, before the database connection times out, proxy server would time out as well.

- As a first thing resolve all DB connectivity issues and test your application by directly connecting to  custom web server (not via proxy).
- Observe and identify normal response time and max response time.
- Set proxy time out [`ProxyTimeout`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxytimeout)  to be a value that is more than (max response time) + (network delay)

If possible you may share proxy server configurations to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

I think like stated by the previous answer that you encounter a timeout raised by one of the members of your infrastructure:

- server
- network device (routers are clever beasts but firewalls can be clever too)

Did you setup a real connection pool ? Using heart beat mechanism to keep alive connections ?
This induces some network traffic but avoids such problems ?
Try to use a network capture tool to have many logs to analyze

HTH
jerome